# Can't register a custom model (based on OpenCV) on Azure Machine Learning service

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to register a model based on cv2.face.createFacemarkLBF with no success.

I'm starting from such a class:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint as pp
from lib.fsclib import logger

LBF_MODEL = model_file = "lbfmodel.yml"

class Landmarker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logger
        self.landmarker = None

    def get_img_gray(self,img):
        return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    def process_landmarks(self, raw_landmarks):
        return raw_landmarks

    def get_landmarks(self, img_gray, face_coords):
        pass

class MyLandmarker(Landmarker):
    def __init__(self, model=LBF_MODEL):
        super(MyLandmarker).__init__()
        logger.info("Initializing FACEMARK with model: %s"%model)
        self.landmarker = cv2.face.createFacemarkLBF()
        self.landmarker.loadModel(model)

    def get_landmarks(self,image, face):
        landmarks = None
        try:
            ok, landmarks = self.landmarker.fit(self.get_img_gray(image), face)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error on class - %s - landmarking failed - %s"%(self.__class__.__name__,str(e)))
        return landmarks
```

...and I want to deploy it according to what explained in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#registermodel

How can I deploy such OpenCV-based face landmarking model in ML Studio?

Thanks,
c

Comment: Registering a model means to upload a trained model (i.e. some binary file). Is that really what you are looking for or do you rather want to train a model=

Answer (score 1):

You would want to register your model file (lbfmodel.yml) and required source files (in this case landmarker.py) - easiest to do by pointing the Model.register command at a directory.

These can be referenced from your driver file as imports and loaded.